# How do I ignore a file using makefile '%' wildcard?

Tags: shell, make

In the following snippet from a Makefile, how would I avoid running `asciidoctor` command if the current file is, for example, 'list.html'.

```
%.html: src/%.m4
        @echo $@
        @asciidoctor -s -a linkcss -a stylesheet=plain.css src/$(LATEST).adoc
        @m4 -D__latest=$(LATEST) $< > out/$@
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make an explicit rule for `list.html` that overrides the wildcard.

I don't have your `asciidoctor` or `m4` setup, so I'll show this with just `cp` and  `:` as the actions for the rules (the `:` is necessary here because an empty rule with no action will not work, in your case you'd run `m4` without `asciidoctor` for `list.html`), with the following `Makefile`:

```
list.html:
    : do nothing for $@

%.html: %.m4
    cp $< $@
```

Example run:

```
$ touch x.m4 list.m4
$ make x.html list.html
cp x.m4 x.html
: do nothing for list.html
```

---

`:` is the "null command" in sh.  From `help :` in bash:

> :: :
> Null command.
>
> ```
> No effect; the command does nothing.
>
> Exit Status:
> Always succeeds.
> ```

Output can be suppressed as usual with `@:`.  `true` or `@true` would work too.

Comment: Thanks. Your example helped me understand how to override the behaviour for individual files. Simple, but powerful.